# Is there anyway that I can display the emails received to webmail in a website?

Tags: php, email, webmail

I have a shared hosting with cPanel and I created some email IDs like email@domain.com. To access emails I do open webmail and check the emails. Is there anyway that I can display the emails in my website?

Comment: There are fully fledged php webmail applications you could with a re-branded template, or you could strip it down and include it into your own website. You could get a prebuilt email class from github/phpclasses or even roll your own with PHP's Mail classes here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.remote.mail.php .. which option do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I can display the emails in my website?

If I read this correct, you want to display mails you received on a certain mailbox on a website. In that case you could for example read the mailbox using [IMAP or POP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). You probably don't want to do this for each visitor.

Comment: Is there any samples available in the Internet? Where can I learn that?